# PHP Login Script Help - Using PDO and Posted variables

Tags: php, pdo

Ok, first things first. I'm attempting to build a website based on this [coding example](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/).

This example using mysql queries instead of PDO queries, so I am trying to change the login (and eventually registration) scripts over to PDO. I have a database prepared with an example username and password to test the script. However, my query always returns false.  I'm not sure if I'm handling the passed variables properly or not. I know I'm connecting to the database fine. Here is my code that is giving me issues. This picks up directly after the page checks to make sure that a username and password have been entered successfully.

```
if(!count($err))
{
    $_POST['username'] = $con->quote($_POST['username']);
    $_POST['password'] = $con->quote($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    // Escaping all input data

            //$loginquery = $con->prepare("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='{".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
            //$myquery = $con->query($loginquery);

            $loginquery = $con->prepare("Select id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr=:username AND pass=:password");
    $loginquery->execute(array(':username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));

    $row = $loginquery->fetchAll();

    if($row['usr'])
    {
        // If everything is OK login

        $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
    }
    else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    //else $err[]= print_r($row['usr']);
```

I commented out some of the code so that I could try different things. I added the final line so that it would (hopefully) display what was being returned by my query. All that it returns is "1", which is the ID number of the row my test username and password are on.  I'm not sure if that is a coincidence or not. As is, I am not receiving any more errors. I simply receive the "Wrong username and/or password!" message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nothing cool actually in this tutorial. It's ugly and wrong.

Comment: Sidenote: A mix of old and new technology. `$old="MD5";` `$new="PDO";` - Don't use the first one ;-)

Comment: This one's a real can of worms .V.V.V.V.V.

Comment: Yes, this IS quite ugly. But it's for a semester project and not something I'm making for long term use or professional reasons. I'll pretty it up after I make everything work properly. Also, Fred - I'm not sure what you are telling me to do regarding the $new="PDO" line. are you saying I should change: "$password=md5($_POST['password']);" to "$password=PDO($_POST['password']);"?

Comment: No, i'm saying that MD5 is very old password storage technology that can no longer be trusted. Use `crypt()` or `brypt()` or `password_hash()`

Answer (score 0):

When using placeholders, you do **NOT** quote/escape the data. The DB system will take care of that for you. Because you've manually added escapes to the data, those escapes will themselves get escaped by the DB as part of the query system, and no you're inserting something different than what was provided:

```
$loginquery->execute(array(':username'=>$_POST['username'], ':password'=> $_POST['password']));
```

is literally all you need to do. And note the `:` on the password parameter. It was missing in your version. The `:` MUST be present when passing placeholder:value pairs in to `exec().

Comment: Thank you, Marc. Those escapes were in the code before I decided to use placeholders. I was beginning to suspect that escaped characters were going to be part of the issue, but I hadn't quite made the connection just yet.

Comment: I commented out the escape lines, and where I posted the variables to new variables.  ThenI just used your script plus "$row = $loginquery->fetch();" and it is working just fine.  Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

fetchAll() returns not what you think. **Always** read the function description in the manual. And then choose more appropriate method.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info also helps

Comment: Thanks for that! I used the code example from @marc_b below, plus the change to the fetchAll() line, and now my login script is working great. Now on to the next set of hurdles.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```
 $loginquery->execute(array(':username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
```

Remove **:** on Parameters!

Comment: Downvote? Why? Thats a correct answer for **a** problem. The **execute** method must not have any colons on parameters. Only the Placeholders **on the Query** must have colons.

Comment: Better yell at the PHP documentation maintainers, then: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php. Without the `:`, there'd be no way to differentiate between a placeholder `:where`, and the sql reserved word `where`. Yes, it'd be silly to use such an obviously reserved word as a placeholder, but since the `:` differentiates everything, it's not an actual conflict.

Comment: @MarcB what reserved word has to do here? you don't send reserved words via prepared statement. That's not an argument.

Comment: yep, i **dont see* reserved words. Where we can found it? Nope,.. no reserved words are on the Statement/query.

Comment: @Adrian just verify your statements before issuing them. To write a proof code will take no more two minutes. And you will see, if colons required or not.

Comment: I'm saying someting like `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = :where`. That's a PERFECTLY valid placeholder name.